# Why the progressBar is being start updating after 2-3 seconds after the other ui's?

Tags: c#, winforms

BytesReceived already at 229120 and TotalBytesToReveive is at 104857600 but the ProgressPercentage is still at 0%

[image: the percentages is still at 0%]

the result is:

[image: progressBar is still at 0%]

then after 2-3 seconds the progressBar start from 3-5% depending on the delay time the progressBar start from 3-5% to catch up the other ui's.

i took a screenshot at 19% but the delay is 2-3 seconds so it start from 3-5%

[image: and then the progressBar start showing the progress]

I can't figure out why the delay happens and how to fix it to make that all the ui's will start get update at the same time. I want to sync timing the progressBar to start at the same time reporting progress with the others.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Download_Files
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        private IProgress<DownloadProgressInfo> progress;

        List<string> links = new List<string>

    {
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/1GB.bin",
    "https://hil-speed.hetzner.com/100MB.bin",
    // Add more URLs as needed
    };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            progress = new Progress<DownloadProgressInfo>(ReportProgress);
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async Task DownloadAsync()
        {
            int totalFiles = links.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++)
            {
                var currentFile = links[i];
                await DownloadFile(currentFile, i, totalFiles);
                await Task.Delay(1000); //set your desired delay period
            }
        }

        private async Task DownloadFile(string currentFile, int i, int totalFiles)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();

                client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = $"Status: Download of file {i + 1}/{totalFiles} completed.";
                    progressBarEx1.Value = 100;
                };

                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    progress.Report(new DownloadProgressInfo
                    {
                        BytesReceived = e.BytesReceived,
                        TotalBytesToReceive = e.TotalBytesToReceive,
                        ProgressPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage
                    });

                    // Calculate download speed
                    double bytesPerSecond = e.BytesReceived / stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

                    // Update label with download speed
                    lblDownloadSpeed.Text = $"Download Speed: {FormatBytes((long)bytesPerSecond)}/s";
                };

                var destinationPath = $@"d:\testfiles\100MB{i}.bin";
                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(currentFile), destinationPath);
            }
        }

        private void ReportProgress(DownloadProgressInfo progressInfo)
        {
            progressBarEx1.Value = progressInfo.ProgressPercentage;
            lblDownloadInfo.Text = $"Download Info: {FormatBytes(progressInfo.BytesReceived)} / {FormatBytes(progressInfo.TotalBytesToReceive)}";
        }

        private async void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DownloadAsync();
        }

        public class DownloadProgressInfo
        {
            public long BytesReceived { get; set; }
            public long TotalBytesToReceive { get; set; }
            public int ProgressPercentage { get; set; }
        }

        public static string FormatBytes(long bytes)
        {
            const int scale = 1024;
            string[] units = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };

            int magnitude = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, scale));

            double adjustedSize = bytes / Math.Pow(scale, magnitude);
            string format = (magnitude > 0 && magnitude < 3) ? "F2" : "F0"; // Show two decimal places for KB and MB, no decimals for others

            return $"{adjustedSize.ToString(format)} {units[magnitude]}";
        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The base class `DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs` defines the ProgressPercentage as an `int`. So does you own `DownloadProgressInfo` class . `229120 / 104857600` = `0` when the result is an `int`. Note that the ProgressBar uses `float` values instead. Calculate the progress percentage yourself, which is just `(float)BytesReceived / TotalBytesToReceive`. Also note that the ProgressBar allows to specify the decimals in the percentage. Set them to `4` (the maximum, unless you change it) -- You shouldn't be using WebClient, this class is obsolete (marked as), try to use HttpClient instead